# Keras + CNTK: TensorSliceWithMBLayoutFor

Tags: keras, cntk

I am running  into a few problems while migrating an image segmentation code done with Keras+Tensorflow backend into Keras+CNTK backend. The code runs perfectly with a TF backend but crashes with CNTK.

The model was inspired from https://github.com/jocicmarko/ultrasound-nerve-segmentation/blob/master/train.py

Model inputs are defined as `inputs = Input((img_width, img_height, num_channels))`, where `num_channels = 1`.

The error comes from the line trying to fit the model:
`model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=trainingEpochs, verbose=2, shuffle=True, validation_data=(X_val, Y_val), callbacks=cb_list)`

Where `X_train`, `Y_train`, `X_val`, `Y_val` are all of shape `(num_slices, img_width, img_height, num_channels)`

The error I keep getting is the following:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "TrainNetwork_CNTK.py", line 188, in 
>       history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=trainingEpochs, verbose=2, shuffle=True, validation_data=(X_val, Y_val), callbacks=cb_list)
>     File "C:\Users...\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1430, in fit
>       initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
>     File "C:\Users...\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1079, in _fit_loop
>       outs = f(ins_batch)
>     File "C:\Users...\site-packages\keras\backend\cntk_backend.py", line 1664, in **call**
>       input_dict, self.trainer_output)
>     File "C:\Users...\site-packages\cntk\train\trainer.py", line 160, in train_minibatch
>       output_map, device)
>     File "C:\Users...\site-packages\cntk\cntk_py.py", line 2769, in train_minibatch
>       return _cntk_py.Trainer_train_minibatch(self, *args)
>   RuntimeError: Node 'UserDefinedFunction2738' (UserDefinedV2Function operation): TensorSliceWithMBLayoutFor: FrameRange's dynamic axis is inconsistent with data:

There seems to be very little activity on CNTK issues here in SO, so anything to try to shine some light to this issue would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the loss function:

```
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)
```

There is a known issue for cntk_keras' flatten implementation, which cause the batch axis shape not matching for this case. Unfortunately, I haven't got a chance to fix it :(

But for your case, I think we don't need the flatten here, right? As you are using K.sum(x) with default axis option, which will apply reduce sum to all axis to get a scale, we should get the same result without flatten it. I tried the loss function below and it seems works:

```
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    intersection = K.sum(y_true * y_pred)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, was shifted from a project for the whole month. I recently tried your suggestion and things seem to work.
Nevertheless, is there an intention to fix this bug for further versions? I upgraded CNTK to the version 2.2 and I encounter the same problem with the flatten implementation.